# Autocorrelation and Mann-Kendall Trend test for multiple timeseries

Tags: r, plyr, apply, stat

I have a very long data frame with 200 stations number. The sample data is given here.
Let the sample data  be`df` .Now
I would like to check the auto correlation at lag 1 for each  station number. Perform pre-whitening and calculate Mann-kendall trend for each stations after pre-whitening. I can do for one individual stations using the code below.
Would you kindly help me how i can perform this for all the stations at once.
Dataframe `df`

```
dput(df)
structure(list(stn_num = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L
), .Label = c("08BB005", "08CE001", "08CF003"), class = "factor"), 
    year = c(1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 
    1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 1980L, 1981L, 1982L, 
    1983L, 1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 
    1992L, 1993L, 1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 1990L, 
    1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L), value = c(411.2146215, 346.9846995, 
    453.8616438, 435.3561644, 421.4019178, 444.7603825, 454.469589, 
    441.5884932, 339.76, 294.9562842, 371.8939726, 321.7016438, 
    337.7627397, 460.6622951, 513.1084932, 385.4580822, 386.6643836, 
    377.9076503, 440.7849315, 407.7731507, 454.4967123, 458.3259563, 
    421.4032877, 449.3890411, 456.3934247, 450.015847, 400.0569863, 
    1331.70765, 1415.484932, 1589.654795, 1606.709589, 1750.002732, 
    1803.646575, 1729.054795, 1802.509589, 1805.469945, 1711.854795, 
    1574.153425)), .Names = c("stn_num", "year", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-38L))
```

Code i have used for individual station's calculation

```
c<-acf(df$value,lag.max=1)
dim(c$acf)
c$acf[[2,1,1]]
df$prewhit1<-c$acf[[2,1,1]]*df$value
prewhitseries<-data.frame(with(df, (df$value[-1] - prewhit1[-length(prewhit1)])))
autocordata<-cbind(df,prewhitseries)
MannKendall(autocordata$prewhitseries)
```

So how i can perform the prewhitening and mankendall test for all the station number on the same dataframe at once.
Thank you.

Comment: Could you run the sample code above at your end and make sure it runs without errors e.g. `autocordata<-cbind(df,prewhitseries)`...cheers

Comment: Second the comment above, the line `prewhitseries<-data.frame(with(df, (df$value[-1] - prewhit1[-length(prewhit1)])))` produces a data.frame with only 37 rows which  you then try to bind to one with 38. Also I'm a little confused on how your code is only running for one station since df contains data for two stations and the you're calculating a lag 1 acf on the entire series at once. Even if the cbind command worked it wouldn't create a column with the name prewhiteseries. Finally if you're using non-base R functions (MannKendall) please specify the package they're from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My above comments aside I think this will get you what you're looking for:

```
stationList <- unique(df$stn_num)
resultsList <- vector("list", length(stationList))
for(i in stationList){
  tempDF <- df[df$stn_num == i, ]
  c<-acf(tempDF$value,lag.max=1)
  t <- dim(c$acf)
  tempDF$prewhit1<-c$acf[[t[1], t[2], t[3]]]*tempDF$value
  prewhitseries<-data.frame(with(tempDF, (tempDF$value[-1] - prewhit1[-length(prewhit1)])))
  autocordata<-cbind(tempDF[-1,],prewhitseries)
  resultsList[[grep(i, stationList)]] <- MannKendall(autocordata[,5])
}
names(resultsList) <- stationList
```

I arbitrarily removed a row from the tempDF I create in the loop so the cbind command will actually work I'm not sure what you actually want to do there. You could get the same result with something from the apply family which might be the direction you want to go if you're trying to parallelize or need more efficiency.

Comment: Thank you Adam. This helps.